# MagiX export project to AVI

Tags: video, multimedia

The whole day I struggled hard for a presentation of a video that I need it for tomorrow. When I am trying to export that project to AVI format, its throwing me an error message stating:

`During export with an external codec, an error has occured. Please check and adjust the export settings...`

How can I overcome this?

Comment: The Magix software doesn't work on Linux. Did you install it in Wine or do you mean a different application?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Magix system, but if this project is able to output successfully into ANY video format, then your best bet is to export the video, then transfer with [ffmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg).

There is a free GUI utility for ffmpeg called [winff](http://winff.org/html_new/) , available from the default ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo aptitude install winff
```

[image]

It's easy,(for a video conversion application) ... and it does the conversion really well from almost any format to almost any other.

Screenshots from winff:

[image]